# WPF TextBox lostfocus as attached property

Tags: wpf, textbox, grid, attached-properties, lostfocus

I have a Grid with many TextBoxes and I want to call `NotifyPropertyChanged()`  method  to update some other controls everytime one of these TextBox-es changed the value = lost the focus (**I don't want** to use `PropertyChanged` as `UpdateSourceTrigger`)

This is what I can do:

```
<Grid TextBoxBase.TextChanged="My_TextChanged"  >
...
</Grid>
```

I need something like:

```
TextBoxBase.OnLostFocus
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the lost focus event

```
TextBox.LostFocus="OnTextBoxLostFocus"
```

Filter on textboxes ;)

```
private void OnTextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!(e.OriginalSource is TextBox))
        return;

    //Do stuff
}
```

If your properties are not changed, your Textboxes will not be updated however. You should consider mutating the data those other TextBoxes are bound to, instead of using LostFocus to update your model.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`TextBoxBase.LostFocus` is, I suspect, the event you're looking for.

It's listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase_events.aspx - but it's defined on `UIElement` - so you possibly want to try `UIElement.LostFocus` if the above doesn't work in markup.

Comment: Edited for fix (sorry, can't test from here).